# Qt сигналы и слоты. Передать переменную в материнскую форму из дочерней

Tags: c++, qt, signal

В общем, встала такая задача - узнать, отрыта ли форма "about" или нет, для того чтобы не открывать ее дубликат. Решил реализовать проверку через сигналы и слоты. Допустим, я нажимаю кнопку F1, посылается сигнал в дочернюю форму, там переменная инкрементируется и возвращается обратно. Если инкрементация не произошла, или переменная вовсе не вернулась, то, стало быть, программа считает что форма либо не открыта либо даже вовсе не открывалась.
Вызов дочерней формы происходит так:

```
int AboutStatus = 1;
QPointer<about> frm = new about;
connect(this,SIGNAL(send(int)),frm,SLOT(getSended(int)));
emit send(AboutStatus);
frm->show();
```

Ну и вот тут мне непонятно кое-что... Во-первых, весь этот connect не работает без

```
QPointer<about> frm = new
```

или

```
about *frm = new about;
```

А мне ведь не надо открывать главную форму по-новой. И главное, непонятно чем в дочерней форме заменить

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(send(int)),frm,SLOT(getSended(int)));
```

Чтобы передать переменную в слот родительской формы.

Comment: Бывает такое состояние которое называется `ерунда какая-то`. Так вот, что вы пытаетесь сделать в целом? Почему где-то в коде надо знать, что открыто/закрыто окно `About`? )

Comment: Потому что если не знать, то окно About открывается каждый раз при нажатии кнопки F1, а надо сделать так, чтобы количество одновременно открытых окон About не превышало одного.

Answer (score 2):

Есть пара способов сделать эту проверку.

Вариант 1. В методе показа окна объявить статическую переменную/указатель данного окна

```
void Window::showAbout() {
    static About about; 
    about.setVisible(!about.isVisible());
}
```

Вариант 2. Поле класса.

```
class Window {
private:
    void showAbout() {
        about.setVisible(!about.isVisible());
    }
    About about;
}
```

Вариант 3. Показывать окно в модальном режиме (`About` должно наследовать `QDialog`, или самостоятельно реализовать использование `QEventLoop`)

```
void Window::showAbout() {
    About about;
    about.exec(); 
}
```

Вариант 4. Создавать указатель и удалять после закрытия окна

```
void Window::showAbout() {
    About* about = new About();
    connect(about, &About::finished, about, &About::deleteLater(), Qt::QueueConnection);
    about->show();
}
```

Вариант 5. Блокировать пункт меню (Disable) пока окно открыто и отлавливать событие `QDialog::finished`, или какое-нибудь кастомное

Answer (score 0):

А зачем это делать именно сигналами? Не проще это делать мьютексами?

Определить глобальный QMutex в mainwindow, при инициализации формы [пытаться заблокировать мьютекс](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#tryLock) и при неудаче выходить

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ отправить сигнал в дочернюю форму, хоть это и не решило моей проблемы, так как сигналы отрабатываются даже если форма не видна. Так или иначе, тут вся фишка в том, что connect надо прописывать в исходнике материнской формы, а не в дочерней, и выглядеть это должно примерно следующим образом:

```
   connect(About, &about::signalSend, this, &MainWindow::slotCatch);
```